# In a iOS app, how to share photos with another iCloud user without sharing the full UIImage, having iCloud handle this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, icloud, photokit

Many thanks for your help. I am developing an application in Swift for iOS 12+, using Xcode 11. It is a travelling application, and has a "Trip" Core Data entity. Each trip can hold notes, and I would like to use this library, [ZSSRichTextEditor](https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSSRichTextEditor), to let the user edit and store the notes in rich text, optionally containing images. As it is, the library can insert images as links on the internet, or from the user Photos library. When using the latter option, the library takes the full UIImage and encodes it as base64, then it inserts it in the WKWebView that the library uses under the hood. Here comes my problem. I would like to let users of my app share trips between them, but I would like to not include the full pictures in the shared trip file, but references to the iCloud photo. Can somebody suggest a possible implementation ? Many thanks.